# DJANGO Templates dont share static files

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a currently have a problem. I got two django templates:`cart.html` and `index.html`. In the `cart.html`  there is a javascript file linked. Both of these files should access the static files in the  `static` folder.

The problem now is that, when I try to acces the static files from the linked `cart.html` javascript file it gives me this error:

> [15/Aug/2022 20:14:40] "GET /cart/images/fruits/Kornknacker.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2419

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'SemmelBrothers.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'template'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'SemmelBrothers.wsgi.application'
```

Here is the project structure:

[image: Project]

Here is the javascript file:

```
{% load static %}
function loadCart() {
    let productsSection = document.getElementById("products_section");
    productsSection.innerHTML = '';
    let productHTML = '';
    let totalPrice = 0;
    let cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    if (cartItems && cartItems.length > 0) {
        for (let item of cartItems) {
            totalPrice = totalPrice + (item.quantity * item.price);
            productHTML = productHTML + `
        <div class="product-card" data-name="${item.itemName}" data-price="${item.price}" data-id="${item.itemId}">
        <div>
            <img src="{%static '/images/fruits/${item.itemName}.jpg'%}" alt="FRUIT" width="180">
        </div>
        <h3>
        ${item.itemName}
        </h3>
        <div>
            Anzahl: ${item.quantity}
        </div>
        <div>
            Preis: ${item.quantity * item.price}€
        </div>
    </div>
        `;
        }
        document.getElementById("total_price_container").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML = totalPrice;
        document.getElementById("no-products_section").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("checkout-section").style.display = 'flex';
        document.getElementById("order-process_section").style.display = 'none';
        productsSection.innerHTML = productHTML;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("no-products_section").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("checkout-section").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("total_price_container").style.display = 'none';
    }
};
loadCart();

document.getElementById('checkout_cart').addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(localStorage);
    localStorage.removeItem('cart');
    document.getElementById("products_section").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("order-process_section").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("checkout-section").style.display = 'none';

})
document.getElementById('clear_cart').addEventListener('click', function () {
    localStorage.removeItem('cart');
    loadCart();
})
```

Comment: Please provide snippet of settings.py file of Django

Comment: Added the code snippets

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that django can't didn't find (404)
"Kornknacker.jpg"
in

```
"static/cart/images/fruits/Kornknacker.jpg"
```

But you should probably point it to

```
"static/images/fruits/Kornknacker.jpg"
```

if that's the case try **Im not sure if it will actually work**:

```
<img src="{%static '/../images/fruits/${item.itemName}.jpg'%}" alt="FRUIT" width="180">
```

Comment: That solution doesn't work. It has something to do with javascript modifiying the html code. This is where the image is searched:
**Anfrage-URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/images/fruits/Kornknacker.jpg**

Comment: could you please provide the folders structure in depth and inspect the <img/> element as  screens shots if it possible.

Comment: most likely, the image has another extension.